# page jump in Chrome and Opera with jquery

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, opera

I have a content slider script that works fine for me in FF, IE and Safari, but not in Chrome and Opera.

When I click on the link in the content navigation, the page jumps up to the next parent div. This just happens in Chrome and Opera.

Any Idea what the problem might be?

here is the script code:

```
$(document).ready(function (){

var itemCount = $('.container div').size();
var itemWidth = $('.container div').width();


$('.container').wrap('<div id="AboutSlider"></div>');

$('#AboutSlider').css({'width':'640px', 'overflow':'hidden', 'position':'relative', 'height':'400px'});

$('#AboutSlider .container').css({'width':itemCount*itemWidth+'px', 'position':'absolute', 'height':'400px'});

$('.container .aboutContent').css({'padding-left':'0px'});

$('#AboutSlider .aboutContent').css({'width':'640px', 'float':'left', 'min-height':'400px'});


$('#AboutNav a').click(function (event) {
    // get the scroll top position
var top = $(window).scrollTop();

event.preventDefault();
$(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + ' ');
var integer = $(this).attr("rel");
$('#AboutSlider .container').animate({
    left: -640 * (parseInt(integer) - 1)
})
$('#AboutNav a').each(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    if ($(this).hasClass('button' + integer)) {
        $(this).addClass('active')
    }
});
document.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");

    // set the scroll top position to its previous value

setTimeout(function(){$(window).scrollTop(top);},1000);
$(window).scrollTop( top );
});

});
```

and here the slider html bit:

```
   <div id="Dienstleistungen">
        <div class="left_column">
        <h2>Meine Dienstleistungen</h2>
        <h3>KOMPETENZEN</h3>
        <ul id="AboutNav">
            <li><h1><a href="#Kompetenzen" class="button1 active noScroll" rel="1" title="Frontend Entwicklung | Sebastian B&ouml;hme">&Uuml;berblick</a></h1></li>
            <li><h1><a href="#Frontend" class="button2 noScroll" rel="2" title="Frontend Entwicklung | Sebastian B&ouml;hme">Frontend Entwicklung</a></h1></li>
            <li><h1><a href="#CMS" class="button3 noScroll" rel="3" title="Content Management Systeme &amp; Online Shops | Sebastian B&ouml;hme">Content Management Systeme &amp; Online Shops</a></h1></li>
            <li><h1><a href="#SEO" class="button4 noScroll" rel="4" title="Suchmaschinenoptimierung (SEO) | Sebastian B&ouml;hme">Suchmaschinenoptimierung (SEO)</a></h1></li>
            <li><h1><a href="#ScreenDesign" class="button5 noScroll" rel="5" title="Screen Design | Sebastian B&ouml;hme">Screen Design</a></h1></li>
            <li><h1><a href="#Hand" class="button6 noScroll" rel="6" title="Alles aus einer Hand | Sebastian B&ouml;hme">Alles aus einer Hand</a></h1></li>
        </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="container">

        <div id="Kompetenzen" class="aboutContent right_columns">
            <h1>&Uuml;berblick</h1>
            <p>Phasellus in massa. Curabitur dolor eros, gravida et, hendrerit ac, cursus non, massa. Aliquam lorem. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras eu mauris. Quisque lacus. Donec ipsum. Nullam vitae sem at nunc pharetra ultricies. Vivamus elit eros, ullamcorper a, adipiscing sit amet, porttitor ut, nibh. Maecenas adipiscing mollis massa. Nunc ut dui eget nulla venenatis aliquet. Sed luctus posuere justo. Cras vehicula varius turpis. Vivamus eros metus, tristique sit amet, molestie dignissim, malesuada et, urna.
            </p>
            <p>Teng sit amet, porttitor ut, nibh. Maecenas adipiscing mollis massa. Nunc ut dui eget nulla venenatis aliquet. Sed luctus posuere justo. Cras vehicula varius turpis. Vivamus eros metus, tristique sit amet, molestie dignissim, malesuada et, urna.
            </p>
        </div>
    <hr />
        <div id="Frontend" class="aboutContent right_column ">
            <h1>Frontend Entwicklung</h1>
            <p>Phasellus..</p>
        </div>
    <hr />  
        <div id="CMS" class="aboutContent right_column ">
            <h1>Content Management Systeme &amp; Online Shops</h1>
            <p>Phasellus..</p>
        </div>
    <hr />
        <div id="SEO" class="aboutContent right_column ">
            <h1>Suchmaschinenoptimierung (SEO)</h1>
            <p>Phasellus..</p>
        </div>
    <hr />
        <div id="ScreenDesign" class="aboutContent right_column ">
            <h1>Screen Design</h1>
            <p>Phasellus..</p>
        </div>
    <hr />
        <div id="Hand" class="aboutContent right_column">
            <h1>Alles aus einer Hand</h1>
            <p>Curabitur..</p>
        </div>
        </div><!-- AboutSlider -->
    </div><!-- Dienstleistungen -->
```

Comment: Does it still happen when you comment out this line? `document.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");`

Comment: No, it doesn't. But I need that line for another functionality of this script which puts the respective # link of the clicked navigation a tag in the url. Do you know any workaround maybe? Thx! ps: this functionality also uses this line: $(this).attr('href',$(this).attr('href')+' ');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the `click` handler for the nav to this:

```
$('#AboutNav a').click(function (event) {
        // get the scroll top position
    var top = $(window).scrollTop();

    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + ' ');
    var integer = $(this).attr("rel");
    $('#AboutSlider .container').animate({
        left: -640 * (parseInt(integer) - 1)
    })
    $('#AboutNav a').each(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        if ($(this).hasClass('button' + integer)) {
            $(this).addClass('active')
        }
    });
    document.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");

        // set the scroll top position to its previous value
    $(window).scrollTop( top );
});
```

It grabs the `scrollTop` position of the `window` at the beginning, then sets it after you update the hash. Not sure if it will work, but worth a try.

Comment: Yes it works perfectly for chrome, thx! But unfortunately I still have the same problem in Opera.. Any more suggestions?

Comment: @Sebsemillia: I'm guessing it is a timing issue. You could try placing that last line of code in a `setTimeout` in order to delay its execution.  `setTimeout(function(){$(window).scrollTop(top);},200);` Here the `200` is the number of milliseconds for the delay. If you experience a jump in some browsers like Chrome, then you may actually want to do both. Just add the `setTimeout` code next to the last line instead of replacing it.

Comment: No sorry, doesn't fix it for Opera.

Comment: @Sebsemillia: If you haven't already, try setting it to a longer duration, like `1000`.

Comment: No, sorry, makes no difference. I updated the code in my question, so that you can see what I tried.

Comment: @Sebsemillia: I really don't know why that would be. In a simple test, `scrollTop()` works for me in Opera, so I'm not sure why it wouldn't here. Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: @Sebsemillia: Here's one more thought. Seems a little hackish, and I don't know if it will work at all. But when you do `document.location.hash = xyz`, maybe you could modify the value you're writing so it doesn't match anything on the page. So if the value is `"Frontend"` you do `...hash = $(this).attr("href") + "_"` making it `"Frontend_"`. Then in the other part of your application, that needs it, you could strip away that trailing `_` with `document.location.hash.slice(0,-1)` which will give you `"Frontend"` again. May be worth a try anyway.

Comment: @Patrick: Thank you for your efforts! But it doesn't fix the issue. I decided to rewrite my script. Maybe, since I know now what I have to consider from the beginning I can use a more sophisticated approach and maybe can fix the problem. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: @Sebsemillia: You're welcome. If this answer was helpful in leading you to your conclusion, please "accept" it by checking the large checkmark to the left of it. Thanks, and best of luck!